# Chrome 90 adds https to Angular localhost app on CORS preflight

Tags: google-chrome, cors

I detected an unusual behaviour in Google Chrome 90.

I have an Angular application (dev port 4200) served in plain http, because it's just a local environment. The back end is a .NET Core 5 app running https on port 5001 on Kestrel.

Today all my `OPTIONS` preflight requests started to fail.

I found that Chrome makes preflight requests by using `https://localhost:4200` instead of `http`, and fails because .NET backend is not allowing localhost in https.

When I find the Preflight request, I copy its Powershell equivalent which is

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://localhost:5001/api/v1/secure/xxxx" `
-Method "OPTIONS" `
-Headers @{
"Accept"="*/*"
  "Access-Control-Request-Method"="GET"
  "Access-Control-Request-Headers"="authorization"
  "Origin"="https://localhost:4200"
  "User-Agent"="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36"
  "Sec-Fetch-Mode"="cors"
  "Sec-Fetch-Site"="same-site"
  "Sec-Fetch-Dest"="empty"
  "Referer"="https://localhost:4200/"
  "Accept-Encoding"="gzip, deflate, br"
}
```

The response is a blank `204 No Content`. If I amend this script to use `https://` as origin, the response contains the desired CORS headers.

The application is served in http. I have the `Insecure` warning on my browser bar, but it's just fine as it is.

Other than working it around, how can I fix this? Could it be a bug in Chromium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Porkaround

Add `https://localhost:4200` as CORS origin in the backend, but this may mean recompiling/reloading/redeploying according to YMMV

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for anybody with a cordova App.

I have reworked my requests to use the cordova advanced-http plugin instead:

https://github.com/silkimen/cordova-plugin-advanced-http

This gives more control and prevents the worry about CORS.